# How to deal with a non-employee who is working in our project and the manager is okay with it

Tags: india, job-description

An employee recently left the company (say Company 1) and joined elsewhere (say Company 2). The new company (Company 2) that he joined has allowed permanent work from home. So, he completed some of the tasks of the new company (Company 2). After that my manager called him and asked him to work for him (in Company 1), and he agreed without any penny from the old company (Company 1). He was working in React  & Node JS (in Company 2), and now he is working in Angular and Java (in Company 1).

Well, that is none of my concern. Until, the manager gave him more tasks than me. **My experience and knowledge in Angular is as much as him, if not more**. But, still I am being denied for the project that my manager had initally assigned me to do. Now for two weeks, while he is almost leading the project, along with the Manager's nephew, who has less than 1 year of experience, I am not even allowed to attend meetings with the client who was going to explain the workflow.

In many cases, this employee, along with the Manager's nephew, do not follow industry standard coding structure, which will posses problem during maintainance of the project.

I am afraid that either the company is going to fire me, because they got a free employee, or something else is going on.

How can I re-affirm my position in the company.

Comment: It's not clear to me why this employee would perform work for Company 1 without and compensation and be, as you put it, a "free employee".  Clearly there is something else going on.

Comment: Why do you care if this employee works on this project, a project, that you are not assigned to? You must be assigned to a different project.  You should focus on your own work

Comment: @jwh20 The employee is happy because he got a 5 times increase in salary when he switched to the new company. Now, he is working in REact and Node in company 2 and Angular and java in Company 1. So, he can update his resume with more skills. So more offers from companies in the future.

Comment: Apparently I cannot join Company 2 , because that only hires from referrals. THe employee will never refer me there. His sister did for him, but no one for me. Despite we both having experience in the same technology

Comment: "But, still I am being denied for the project that my manager had initally assigned me to do."  Did your manager give you a reason for the denial?

Comment: Nope. I spent 1+ months in learning that skill. Maybe it's because the manager's nephew is friends with this employee, and the nephew is the team lead of the project (despite having less exp than me which is something I really dont care). I care about my project and freedom to implement my ideas

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately there probably isn't much that you can do.

Your company is obviously happy to get free labour (or whatever the deal is that you might not be aware of), and your manager seems to be fine with cutting corners to prioritise results over good standards. Which in fairness does need to be done sometimes.

Will this come back to haunt them? Who knows... it isn't for you to decide anyway.

If you are set on trying to improve your situation then the best thing to do is have a one-on-one with your manager and explain your concerns and see if there is something you can both work towards where everyone is happy. Perhaps you can specifically ask for more tasks/responsibility. Or ask to be included in the project more.

However, if an agreement cannot be made that you are happy with, then it comes down to the usual... either suck it up and accept it, or find yourself a new job.

Comment: " either suck it up and accept it" - I dont have a problem with that. But, I have spent the last 1.5 months in learning new technology, just so I could work for this project. Now, he and the manager's nephew are almost ruining it. I am not saying I am a genius, but I know that I am not wrong in some cases.

Comment: @Asish: Learning something new is never a waste. You may not get to use that knowledge right now, but it will be there in the future if and when you need it. Also, it's only going to improve your CV (resume) and future prospects.

Comment: @Asish: Personally, it sounds more like you are just a bit demoralised at the moment. It's always difficult to think you are heading in one direction only to end up being pulled in a different one. This however is the reality of life, and ultimately it is a learning experience that will help you grow as a person. Try to find the positives out of it (learning something new) and just roll with it. Focus on doing your own tasks to the best of your ability, and make yourself standout on your own merits, don't worry so much about what others are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I didn't consider learning new tech as a waste. I just get bored sitting ideal for most of the time, and not being able to implement my own ideas

Comment: I hope to get a positive experience out of it.